# Installing Ant is overriding Java Installation

Tags: java, openjdk

I am trying to install ANT after installing java. My java in Sun Java.

```
pc19@pc19-H110:~$  java -version
java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)
```

---

```
pc19@-H110:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20/bin/java
```

---

```
pc19@pc19-H110:~$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20/bin/java
```

---

```
pc19@-H110:~$ sudo apt-get install ant
```

---

```
pc19@-H110:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.20.1" 2023-08-24
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I install ANT using `sudo apt get install ant`, it is overring the Sun Java insallation with OpenJdk installation. Does anybody know the workaround for it?

Why is ant installation overriding java? How do I stop it?